# Calling a function with Go Reflect

Tags: go, reflect

I was wondering if it was possible to not know a function name but call it anyway and get values from it. This lead me to the reflection package and I got pretty close but I’m not sure about the last step - if there is one. Again please forgive me if I am missing something obvious, this is my first attempt at doing anything in Go other than getting it setup.

Of course being a compiled language there is no need to iterate through things to find function names, I know them all, but this is something I want to see if it is possible… I’m playing and learning.

Below is the code. What I would really like to do is in the main line extract the values set in ModuleBoot() <“1.0012”, 23> and SomethingBoot() <“1.0000”, 10> but so far all as I can get is structure information. Perhaps that’s just the way it is but perhaps there is a step or change that can make it go the next step.

Hopefully I copied all the relevant code over correctly so it compiles as is:

```
// Using: go version go1.9.7 linux/amd64
=======================================
FILE: main.go
=======================================
package main

import (
  "fmt"
  "reflect"
  "playing/modules/core"
)

func main() {

  miType := reflect.TypeOf(core.ModuleInfo{})

  fmt.Println("")

  for i := 0; i < miType.NumMethod(); i++ {
    method := miType.Method(i)
    fmt.Println(method.Name)

    in := make([]reflect.Value, method.Type.NumIn())
    in[0] = reflect.ValueOf(core.ModuleInfo{})
    //fmt.Println("Params in:", method.Type.NumIn(), "Params out:", method.Type.NumOut())

    mi := method.Func.Call(in)
    fmt.Println("mi:", mi)

    fmt.Println("")
  }
}

=======================================
FILE: playing/modules/core/something.go
=======================================
package core

func (mi ModuleInfo) SomethingBoot() ModuleInfo {
  mi.Version = "1.0000"
  mi.Priority = 10
  return mi
}

=======================================
FILE: playing/modules/core/modules.go
=======================================
package core

type ModuleInfo struct {
  Version string
  Priority int
}

func (mi ModuleInfo) ModuleBoot() ModuleInfo {
  mi.Version = "1.0012"
  mi.Priority = 23
  return mi
}
```

The output I got from this was:

```
Started delve with config "Debug"

SomethingBoot
mi: [<core.ModuleInfo Value>]

ModuleBoot
mi: [<core.ModuleInfo Value>]

delve closed with code 0
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get the return value as a ModuleInfo, get the [underlying value](https://godoc.org/reflect#Value.Interface) of the first return value and [type assert](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Type_assertions) that interface value to ModuleInfo:

```
// mi has type core.ModuleInfo
mi := method.Func.Call(in)[0].Interface().(core.ModuleInfo)
```

[Run it on the Playground](https://play.golang.org/p/1jlWbSlri94).

You can cut some of the reflect code by type asserting the method to a function with the correct signature and calling that function directly:

```
for i := 0; i < miType.NumMethod(); i++ {
    method := miType.Method(i).Func.Interface().(func(core.ModuleInfo) core.ModuleInfo)
    mi := method(core.ModuleInfo{})
    fmt.Println("Version", mi.Version)
    fmt.Println("Priority", mi.Priority)
    fmt.Println("")
}
```

[Run it on the Playground](https://play.golang.org/p/1diQZdO6M6p)

Comment: Awesome, thank you!
I also came across this great resource while looking around for anyone who's looking into this: https://github.com/a8m/reflect-examples

Comment: On this 2nd example without reflection I couldn't get it to work when ModuleInfo is the imported package "core" (see code above). I get:
./main.go:42:65: undefined: ModuleInfo
./main.go:43:16: undefined: ModuleInfo
and when I try to reference the module like this: method := miType.Method(i).Func.Interface().(func(core.ModuleInfo) core.ModuleInfo) I get compile errors:
./main.go:43:16: undefined: ModuleInfo
./main.go:45:29: mi.Priority undefined (type core.ModuleInfo has no field or method Priority).

Comment: I fixed the typo.

Comment: You really know your Go, thank you! I got stuck on one last problem and I'm hoping you can help but I thought it wouldn't be right to post here so I opened up a separate question which is at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53020517/calling-a-method-with-go-reflect-by-name-and-with-a-parameter .

I must admit I'm still trying to digest the line you did: "method := miType.Method(i).Func.Interface().(func(core.ModuleInfo) core.ModuleInfo)" as I don't think I fully understand it yet. I've been matching it against the docs. and I'll eventually get it.

Answer (score 0):

Go natively supports functions as values; you don't need reflection to do this.

In particular, if you make your two functions top-level functions (not specifically tied to a struct):

```
package core
type ModuleInfo struct { ... }
func SomethingBoot() ModuleInfo
func ModuleBoot() ModuleInfo
```

Then you can write a function that takes a function as a parameter:

```
func PrintVersion(func booter() core.ModuleInfo) {
        mi := booter()
        fmt.Printf("version %s\n", mi.Version)
}
```

And you can just pass the pre-existing functions as parameters:

```
PrintVersion(core.SomethingBoot)
PrintVersion(core.ModuleBoot)
```

Notice that there aren't parentheses after the function name: you are passing the function itself as a parameter, not calling the function and passing its return value.

Comment: Thanks for the reply but you hard coded the function names in the call, e.g.: PrintVersion(core.SomethingBoot) which isn't quite what I was asking.