# Calling a method with Go Reflect by name and with a parameter

Tags: go, reflect

This is a follow on from [Calling a function with Go Reflect](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52999602/calling-a-function-with-go-reflect/52999686#52999686) .

To simplify the question I cut out what I could, hard coded some values and ~hopefully~ didn't make it unclear in the process. I'm getting an error on the code "method.Call(env)" near the bottom.

Ideally what I would like to do is minimize the use of reflection similarly how ThunderCat did on the previous question with the line:

```
method := miType.Method(i).Func.Interface().(func(core.ModuleInfo) core.ModuleInfo)
```

but if that's not possible the simplest way it can be done would be perfectly fine. If this seems like a basic question, my apologies, I am very new to Go.

The error I am getting is:

```
cannot use env (type Environment) as type []reflect.Value in argument to method.Call
```

which is because I would like to assert the method to the function with the correct signature as was done on the previous quesiton but after quite a bit of playing around I just haven't quite got it.

The simplified code:

```
package main

import (
  "flag"
  "fmt"
  "reflect"
)

type CommandLineFlags struct {
  Debug *bool
}

type Environment struct {
  CLF CommandLineFlags
}

type ModuleInfo struct {
  Initialize bool   // Flag: True of module has Initialization function and it should be called. Default: false
  Module     string // Name of the module. No need to hard code, will be set during initialization.
}

type ModuleInit struct{}

func main() {
  var env Environment

  env.CLF.Debug = flag.Bool("dbg", false, "Enables Debug Messages")
  flag.Parse()

  modules := make([]ModuleInfo, 1)
  modules[0].Initialize = true
  modules[0].Module = "logger"

  miValue := reflect.ValueOf(ModuleInit{})
  // miType := reflect.TypeOf(ModuleInit{})
  for _, m := range modules {
    if m.Initialize {
      funcName := m.Module + "Init"
      method := miValue.MethodByName(funcName)
      fmt.Println(funcName)
      // Would like to do something like this
      //    ...Func.Interface().(func(core.ModuleInit) core.ModuleInit)
      // like is done with the referenced quesiton above so as to minimize the use of reflect calls.
      method.Call(env)
    }
  }
}

func (mi ModuleInit) LoggerInit(env *Environment) {
  var debugEnabled = *env.CLF.Debug
  // ...and more stuff.
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The method has the type `func(*Environment)`.  [Assert to that type](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Type_assertions) and call:

```
modules := make([]ModuleInfo, 1)
modules[0].Initialize = true
modules[0].Module = "Logger"

miValue := reflect.ValueOf(ModuleInit{})
for _, m := range modules {
    if m.Initialize {
        funcName := m.Module + "Init"
        method := miValue.MethodByName(funcName).Interface().(func(*Environment))
        method(&env)
    }
}
```

[Run it on the Playground](https://play.golang.org/p/d7QcD1BxlUh).

(Note two issues fixed: The module should be `"Logger"`, not `"logger"`, method takes a `*Environment`, not an `Environment`.)

The code above will panic if the method is not found or does not have the correct type. Here's the code with checks to prevent a panic:

```
modules := make([]ModuleInfo, 1)
modules[0].Initialize = true
modules[0].Module = "Logger"

miValue := reflect.ValueOf(ModuleInit{})
for _, m := range modules {
    if m.Initialize {
        funcName := m.Module + "Init"
        method := miValue.MethodByName(funcName)
        if !method.IsValid() {
            fmt.Printf("method %s not found", funcName)
            continue
        }
        fn, ok := method.Interface().(func(*Environment))
        if !ok {
            fmt.Println("method is not func(*Environment)")
            continue
        }
        fn(&env)
    }
}
```

[Run it on the Playground](https://play.golang.org/p/7c5tgDQahul).

Comment: If I know every method I iterate through has exactly the same signature and is therefore valid I gather which is the case, I gather that I don't need the "IsValid()" condition. Or, put in the form of a question, are there methods that could be on the type other than what I program such as internal methods?

Comment: The only methods are those defined by the application.  The code in the question runs afoul both conditions: the valid check handles the incorrect method name and the ok in the type assertion handles the incorrect function signature.  I'd keep this checks and return an error or panic with an informative error message.

Answer (score 1):

There is several errors in OP code,

- the func name was not properly generated,
- the reflected method instance was not properly checked for validity,
- env parameter of LoggerInit was a pointer, a value was sent in,
- method call was not properly done.

Here is the fixed version (https://play.golang.org/p/FIEc6bTvGWJ).

```
package main

import (
    "flag"
    "fmt"
    "log"
    "reflect"
    "strings"
)

type CommandLineFlags struct {
    Debug *bool
}

type Environment struct {
    CLF CommandLineFlags
}

type ModuleInfo struct {
    Initialize bool   // Flag: True of module has Initialization function and it should be called. Default: false
    Module     string // Name of the module. No need to hard code, will be set during initialization.
}

type ModuleInit struct{}

func main() {
    var env Environment

    env.CLF.Debug = flag.Bool("dbg", false, "Enables Debug Messages")
    flag.Parse()

    modules := make([]ModuleInfo, 1)
    modules[0].Initialize = true
    modules[0].Module = "logger"

    miValue := reflect.ValueOf(ModuleInit{})
    // miType := reflect.TypeOf(ModuleInit{})
    for _, m := range modules {
        if m.Initialize {
            funcName := strings.Title(m.Module) + "Init"
            method := miValue.MethodByName(funcName)
            log.Printf("%#v %v\n", method, funcName)
            if !method.IsValid() || method.IsNil() {
                break
            }
            fmt.Println(funcName)
            // Would like to do something like this
            //    ...Func.Interface().(func(core.ModuleInit) core.ModuleInit)
            // like is done with the referenced quesiton above so as to minimize the use of reflect calls.
            out := method.Call([]reflect.Value{reflect.ValueOf(env)})
            fmt.Println(out) // A bunch of relfect.Values.
        }
    }
}

func (mi ModuleInit) LoggerInit(env Environment) {
    var debugEnabled = *env.CLF.Debug
    // ...and more stuff.
    log.Println("LoggerInit ", debugEnabled)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that the argument passed `reflect.Value.Call` needs to be of the type `reflect.Value` itself. See the signature from https://golang.org/pkg/reflect/#Value.Call

`func (v Value) Call(in []Value) []Value`

Answer (score 0):

You must wrap the `env` variable in a `[]reflect.Value` since `reflect.Value.Call` requires a slice of `reflect.Value`.

```
args := []reflect.Value{reflect.ValueOf(&env),}
method.Call(args)
```

Also, some typos in your code:

```
modules[0].Module = "Logger"
```

Comment: Yeah, it's not that way in the original code, that was my mistake as I was trimming it down for here. Those values are gathered through code so really can't be wrong.